# Could not load texture

Tags: python, panda3d

What I want is to load a picture in the Panda3D, but it can't run for the reason of could not load the texture. I really don't know why for the code could run well in the other environment.

```
def run(self):
    base.win.setClearColor((.49, .49, .49, 1))
    pic1 = -1
    block = 1
    trials = 0
    nc = 0
    homescreen = self.picture('Guide.png', duration=0, scale=(1, 1), pos=[0, 0], block=False)
    self.waitfor('space')
    homescreen.destroy()
```

This is the error information:

> File "modules\Exp2test.py", line 24, in run
>       homescreen = self.picture('Guide.png', duration=0, scale=(1, 1), pos=[0, 0], block=False)
>
> IOError: Could not load texture: Guide.png

Comment: Thank you for your question! Where is your picture located relative to your main script?